# Find the Windows OS version including Revision number from PowerShell on a remote system

Tags: powershell

I need to get the OS version and Revision number using PowerShell on a list of remote systems.

I need the results that you get from [environment]::OSVersion.Version but on the remote systems.

when I run [environment]::OSVersion.Version

it returns

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

6      1      7601   65536

the ultimate goal would be for it to look like this (where system name is the remote system I am querying.)

SystemName 6.1.7601.65536

my current code:

```
$expectedVersion = "6.1.7601.65536"
$computer = Get-content "C:\temp\servers.txt"
foreach ($computer in $computer)
{
$a=[environment]::OSVersion.Version 
If ($a -lt $expectedVersion)
{
  Write-Host "$computer $a is NOT Patched" -ForegroundColor Red
}
Else
{
  Write-Host "$computer $a is Patched" -ForegroundColor Green
}}
```

which give me the following results:

System-01 6.1.7601.65536 is Patched

System-02 6.1.7601.65536 is Patched

System-41 6.1.7601.65536 is Patched

System-42 6.1.7601.65536 is Patched

the issue I am having is that the resulting OS version is only of the local system and not the remote systems.

I know this because it is being run from a Win 7 box against a long list of Server and only server OS which are different OS version numbers then what is showing up in the results.

what am I missing here.  can you all help me tweak this to make it work against remote systems?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your coffee sample you first acquire a list of server names and then iterate on them. But within the iteration nothing happens in the target remote server.

What you need to do is to create a script block implementing your query and then on each iteration execute it on the remote server using powershell remoting.

Like this

```
$block={....}
$result=()
foreach($server in $servers)
{
    $result+= Invoke-Command -Computer $server -ScrptBlock $block
 }
```

Powershell remoting is not an easy subject. It requires each target server to have powershell remoting enabled. in the above code your credentials will be used but for advanced variations either by using parameters or extra powershell sessions will allow you to do anything.

If you need more help with remoting then let me know. It's a really big subject to explain with one answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using PSRemoting, you could use a different method get the Operating System version. The WMI class Win32_OperatingSystem contains the version information for a system.

```
$expectedVersion = "6.1.7601.65536"
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\temp\servers.txt"
$OSData = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Servers -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
ForEach ($Entry in $OSData) {
    If ($Entry.Version -lt $expectedVersion) {
        Write-Host "$($Entry.PSComputerName) $($Entry.Versions) is NOT Patched" -ForegroundColor Red
    } Else {
        Write-Host "$($Entry.PSComputerName) $($Entry.Versions) is Patched" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Get-HotFix` to check if a specific patch is installed.

```
$PatchID = 'KB1234567'
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\temp\servers.txt"
$HotFixes = Get-HotFix -ID $PatchID -ComputerName $Servers
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
    if ($Server -notin $HotFixes.PSComputerName) {
        Write-Host "$PatchID missing on $Server" -ForegroundColor Red
    } else {
        Write-Host "$PatchID installed on $Server" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```